# Ubuntu 11.04 Server host w/ VirtualBox and a windows 2003 server guest, doesn't recognize the network adapter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2003, virtualbox

I have an Asus Extreme II motherboard with onboard chipset for ethernet. Running Ubuntu 11.04 Server with VirtualBox. The Windows 2003 Server guest, doesn't recognize the network adapter. Installed the proper driver but getting error 1722, same machine runs xp in another VM fine. Network adapter is set to NAT, installed a newer version of the driver than what Windows was using, but it still doesn't recognize the network adapter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are setting up a server, wouldn't you want a **bridged** connection?  If you don't have a bridged connection it is going to be a PITA, for your clients to connect to the server.

Comment: Why would you want to use unstable Natty for a server? Aside from that though, I had a similar problem and solved it by removing the VBox that was available in the PPA, downloaded and installed the one from the VBox website.

Comment: OK so I have the adapter in vbox set to nat I did try the bridged connection to no avail. I really don't want a bridge conection as I could have 5 different vms using the same port. I have also not had any problems at all with natty for a server